# Loop and Array - code not working due to ineptitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, plot

This is a piece of code I have that corresponds to an HTML document where people enter the terms a, b, and c, of a quadratic equation of the format: ax^2 + bx + c. The problem I am having may be an issue of function scope, or getting the right variables into the array. If you look at the D2 array in the JQuery part of the code (which is irrelevant), you will see the format I need to plot the graph.

```
<td><input id="Term 1" onchange="calculate();"></td>
<td><input id="Term 2" onchange="calculate();"></td>
<td><input id="Term 3" onchange="calculate();"></td>

var graphArray = {};
    function calculate(){
     var T1 = document.getElementById("Term 1");
     var T2 = document.getElementById("Term 2");
     var T3 = document.getElementById("Term 3");
     var U1 = parseFloat(T1.value);
     var U2 = parseFloat(T2.value);
     var U3 = parseFloat(T3.value);

        var yFunction = function(x) {
            return U1 * Math.pow(x, x) + U2 * x + U3;
        };


        for(var x = 1; x <= 20; x++) {
            graphArray.push([x, yFunction(x)]);
        }
        return graphArray;
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        var D1 = [[1, 4], [2, 8], [3, 16], [4, 32]];
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), [graphArray]);
    });
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `graphArray = []` to declare the empty array, the main error it throws concerns `push()` not being a valid method, for it doesn't recognize graphArray to be an array.
I take it the script tags and the inclusion of jquery where omitted out of laziness.

I'm failing to understand what that `$.plot()` business means, so I don't see why you shouldn't declare graphArray inside the calculate function, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Sorry to have offended you with my laziness. Next time, I will print screen my computer so that you can understand precisely everything that is going on. The plot method is part of a jQuery plug in that plots the graph, but you can see from the ordered pair values that that will be the case. I've done it with an array too, the fact I used an object notation was because I had tried a different method after I tried it with an array, and neither have worked. Apparently I was too lazy to change this. But you're right; I'm new to the forum and I will curb my laziness for future posts :p

Comment: No probs... I just mentioned that _hoping_ it was laziness, but one can't know for sure: perhaps your trouble was just lack of correct syntax. You don't need to show the script tags and the inclusion of an external library, but I try separating the code blocks when I'm omitting the obvious.